# Deal with (auth based) socket emit function when it's in another file

Tags: javascript, sockets, react-native

In my react native application I'm using a socket which is created in the `hhSocket.js` file. Here is the code :

```
  socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit('authenticate', {token: 'test token'});
  socket.on('authenticated', function(user){


      socket.emit(channel, data);


  });
  socket.on('unauthenticated', function(err){
    // unauthenticated err message handling
  });
});
```

Before this, I used to directly export the `socket.emit()` function to my main `app.js`, and then, when the user touched a button, it would trigger `socket.emit()` with parameters.

As you can see now, I am using socket.io with an authentification system, allowing socket events only when the user is logged.

Because I can't directly export the socket.emit now (because must be on top-level, and however it is not secure). How can I access this method from `app.js` in a secure manner ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is using a Singleton (there a smarter people than me that explain it online). Basically, you can have this one instance of the socket that you authenticate. After that you can request this instance of the socket from a Singleton from every file that you would need it to. I do this a lot in large scale applications and it just does the trick each and every time. Pretty sure this is what you need.